# Show a custom dialog from my sdk and implement deep linking when user chooses a button from the dialog

Tags: roku

I need to create an sdk which will fetch data from server and present a custom dialog to the user. It might contain some buttons and images.
 When user clicks on the button I have to implement some action on screen like deep linking or something else.
 May I know if it is possible in roku?

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible. To create the dialog you can use https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Dialog

For creating other components and to have proper navigation flow in your app you can refer the following Scene Graph Documentation.

https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/SceneGraph+API+Reference

Comment: I went through those documents, couldn't find a satisfying approach. Is it possible to keep an xml template( a group) in our SDK file and show it as a popup in the app in which SDK is being integrated?

Comment: Yes, You can do that. Create a rectangle node with transparent background of screen size, on top of that create another rectangle node of your popup size and inside this rectangle you can put whatever components you want, e.g. image button etc. It will reflect as a popup to the user

Comment: You should learn how to create the custom components in Roku. https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Creating+Custom+Components

Comment: So if i create a group with the above rectangles as you mentioned, how can I access and display the same from the app on which it is being integrated?Note that xml will be in my SDK files

Comment: I am not sure which kind of SDK you are trying to create. But as far as I know for any channel/app in roku, you need to have only one zip file and your complete code should be present in that only.

Comment: Please just make sure you follow the file/folder structure recommended by Roku and create the sdk accordingly.

Comment: @Abhishek I created a one Dialog and set m.top.dialog = dialog. then It's Working on All Component But I use that Dialog used in another component. Is It Possible.

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya , sorry but I couldn't get your question

Comment: @Abhishek I Explain I created a one scene component and another is Group Component. And I simply Group component to append with Scene Component. In my Group Component available in two text box and two dialog box. I append it. that time only display a two textbox not show a dialog box. Its said our "m.top.dialog" node does not support this interface.